# How to import passwords and logins data to firefox?

Tags: csv, google-chrome, firefox, import

I have a CSV file with all of my passwords from Chrome and want to transfer them all to Firefox. But recently Firefox removed the feature to import login data.
[This feature is currently disabled by default, due to performance issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S1EV.png)

Is there a way to write a script that would iterate through saved login data and push it to Firefox instead of doing it manually one by one?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Go to about:config and search for:
signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled

set it to true, then navigate to about:logins (if already open refresh the page) and hit the 3 dots, Import from File is now an option, import your csv and be happy.

[Image of the added option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6sDn.png)

Comment: If after importing with "Import from File" you don't see a popup with import results and don't see any logins imported, please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600472/23715) from @nikir.

Comment: It's 2023, Firefox is up to v117 and the documentation STILL thinks this is enabled by default.

Comment: This works FF 117 on MacOS

Answer (score 30):

There seems to be a bug in the current version of Firefox (104) preventing the import of passwords. A second step is (temporarily) necessary. I found a workaround in this [thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/vzq8fj/comment/igg0plb/).

If you encounter this bug, you will need to set

```
security.allow_eval_in_parent_process
```

to `true`, in addition to setting

```
signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled
```

to `true`.

Once you import your login data, you should reset the former to `false`, as it's a security feature.

Comment: missing information: open `about:config` and then change settings above