# Import passwords into firefox 108 previously exported with firefox ESR 52+password exported

Tags: firefox, import, passwords

I exported my passwords to CSV with Firefox-ESR 52+password exporter.

Password-exporter creates a CVS file with the following fields :

```
"hostname","username","password","formSubmitURL","httpRealm","usernameField","passwordField"
```

Than I tried to convert this format to a format acceptable by Firefox 108 containing the following fields :

```
"url","username","password","httpRealm","formActionOrigin","guid","timeCreated","timeLastUsed","timePasswordChanged"
```

with this command :

```
awk -F',' 'BEGIN{print"\"url\",\"username\",\"password\",\"httpRealm\",\"formActionOrigin\",\"guid\",\"timeCreated\",\"timeLastUsed\",\"timePasswordChanged\""}!/^.hostname/&&/^[^#]/{print$1","$2","$3","$5","$4",,,,"}' password-export-2023-01-03.csv > password-export-2023-01-03_TO_NEW_FORMAT.csv
```

Then in `about:config`, I enabled these two parameters to be able to import the CSV passwords file :

`security.allow_eval_in_parent_process` and `signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73600472/5649639).

But still it fails with this error (`Import Error. Unable to Read File Firefox does not have permission to read the file. Try changing the file permissions. No logins have been imported`) although the ACLs on the directory and files are fine.

[Here's a screenshot of what the dialog for the above error message looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuxtV.png).

Comment: Could you please add a link to the tool you used to create the exported passwords CSV?

Comment: @AlexSpurling Password Exporter was an old firefox addon. It can be  installed on old firefox versions (v52 for example) : https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/firefox/addon/password-exporter/

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution.
Follow the steps below:

- convert your file layout to Header format: username,password,URL
  `echo "username,password,URL" >"$f_out.csv"`
  `awk -F ',' '{print $2","$3","$1}' <"$f_in.txt" >>"$f_out.csv"`
  or change the order of the $1, $2, $3 with that used in your f_in file
- type in the firefox URL: `About:config`
- type in the search preference name field: `signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled`
- set to true
- hit the 3 dots, Import from File is now an option
- choose the file to import, use csv filetype
- type in the URL rule: `About:config`
- type in the search preference name field: `signon.management.page.fileImport.enabled`
- set to false